# multiply a column by different values based on the value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

```
 Groups:   District [1]
  District Year   Homicides  City Yearcode  Post Blackmajor treated
     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1        1 2012          13     1        1     0          1       0
2        1 2013          11     1        2     0          1       0
3        1 2014           9     1        3     0          1       0
4        1 2015-1         3     1        4     0          1       0
5        1 2015-2         8     1        5     1          1       1
6        1 2016          16     1        6     1          1       1
```

What I am trying to do is multiply the homicides column by specific numbers based on the district number. For example, if the district number is 10, the value would be Homicides*1.59, if the district number is 11, the value would be homicides*1.05.

Here is my attempt

```
df<-df %>%
  mutate(Homiciderate=case_when(District==10~df$Homicides*1.59,
                                District==11~df$Homicides*1.05))
```

But I get this error using my full dataframe (363 is the length of my dataframe)

```
 df$Homicides * 1.34`, ... must be length 11 or one, not 363.
i The error occurred in group 1: District = 1
```

Not really sure what I can do?

Comment: Maybe is because you'are using df$Homicides. Use just Homicides instead and tell me how it works.

Comment: Don't use `df$` in a dplyr verb. I should precede that with *"almost never"*, there is a very rare time when it is justified, the rest of the time it is at best inefficient, and typically it corrupts or breaks your calculations.

Comment: The reason "why" you should (almost) never use `df$` inside a dplyr pipe is clearly demonstrated here: when used in groups, it might be that the whole frame as (say) 50 rows and the groups have between 10-20 rows each; when you use `group_by(District) %>% mutate(... Homicide...)`, the reference to `Homicide` has 10-20 values; when you use `group_by(District) %>% mutate(... df$Homicide ...)`, that refers to *all 50 values* (completely ignoring the grouping), and the resulting assignment should have 10-20 values yet will have all 50. Don't do it.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Read carefully r2evans comments. He explains on detail why df$Homicides wasn't a correct approach.